# authentication Django on LDAP server

Tags: django, authentication, web-applications, ldap, authorization

I would like my web application authenticate users on an ldap server (only for username and password), but that the permissions reside on django.

Not all ldap users must have access to the web application.

In particular, I would like to allow users to see only a few records (for example, suppose there is a model with a city field: some users should only be able to see records whose city field is london, others whose city is milano, etc.).

How can i define django permissions if users are defined on ldap?

How can I define the user's application admin if users are defined on ldap?

Do I need to implement a double authentication? Do I have to define ldap users who can access the web application even on django?

What is the best way to proceed?

Do you have any suggestions?

Examples?

Thanks
pacopyc

Answer (score 0):

> Not all LDAP users must have access to the web application.

Create a separate branch in LDAP tree for your application

> What is the best way to proceed? Do you have any suggestions?

Take a look at the [django-python3-ldap](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) extension:
Define your settings in Django settings.py, then do a LDAP sync users to your local database

```
python manage.py ldap_sync_users
```